# Drag and drop implementation while running angular app logic in a webworker

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, web-worker

Based on Angular CLI 1.7.4 (Ubuntu 17.10) I created a small sample app with

```
ng new webWorkerTest
```

and followed the steps at this great guide: [Angular with Web Workers: Step by step](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135). Afterwards I created a component `DraggableComponent`:

```
ng g c draggable
```

and tried to register a *dragstart* listener to that component by adding

```
this.renderer.listen(this.reference.nativeElement, 'dragstart', (event: Event) => {
  console.log('Element drag start');
});
```

to the constructor of this component (in fact I tried a lot more, but this is my best guess ;) ).

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It worked with a `click` or `mousemove` event, but not with `dragstart`. Suprisingly `onDragStart="alert('This one works!');"` in the template worked as well.

**Now my question**: does anyone know, how I could add a `dragstart` listener? Or - if so - why this does/cannnot not work?

My aim is to implement a lean drag and drop functionality based on two simple directives without any libraries.

For curiosity I tried [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) and [ng-drag-drop](https://github.com/ObaidUrRehman/ng-drag-drop). However, both failed in a webworker as well.

Comment: Hey man, I would suggest to change the title/question to something like "implementation of drag and drop API while running angular app logic in a webworker". The topic is indeed interesting but your current question is misleading a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing and trying a lot I’m rather sure that drag events simply don‘t work in the way as described above (at least at this point of time). 
The fact that other libraries ([ngx-drag-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-drag-drop), [dragular](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula)) don’t work in this project setup as well strengthens my assumption. I did not find any explanation why these events do not work at the same time others do.

Click events and mouse events work quite fine and I was able to build my own drag and drop based on mouse events (with some quirks though).

Anyway – while playing around with my app I identified several disadvantages of having the whole app in a web worker:

1. Drag and drop did not work
2. The Angular Material component framework [doesn’t work](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/728) as well
3. All components and services run in the same web worker and can potentially block each other

Therefore, I tried another approach to move my extensive background task into a web worker: [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). With webpack I was able to bundle concerned TypeScript files into one JavaScript file. The TypeScript files reside in my Angular project and the worker bundle gets created into my assets folder. This way I can reuse the same classes on UI and worker thread.

So starting from this idea, I was able resolve all of the issues mentioned above. My drag and drop [implementation](https://www.radzen.com/blog/angular-drag-and-drop/) runs on the UI thread. Including Angular Material was no problem and the extensive background task can be executed in a WebWorker. Communication between UI and WebWorker is based on `postMessage()` commands. That’s it.

Some interesting links around the web worker topic:

- *[Angular with Web Workers: Step by Step](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135)*: wrap complete app  into a WebWorker.
- *[angular2-web-worker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-web-worker)* or *[angular2-web-worker](https://github.com/haochi/angular2-web-worker)*: run a method in a WebWorker
- *[Intro to Angular 2 – Part 5 – WebWorkers](http://blog.brakmic.com/introduction-to-angular-2-part-5-webworkers/)*: initialize a WebWorker and post message to it
- *[Second argument of postMessage is not a transfert list](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/745)*: resolve issue related to `postMessage()` from WebWorker

Answer (score 0):

WebWorkers run on a separate thread from the UI, and do not have access to the DOM.

So, they're not intended to do things like receive events from the DOM.

You should, instead, receive the event (e.g. 'dragstart') on the UI thread (not in the WebWorker), and have that foreground event handler kick off the WebWorker.

The foreground code should receive the response from the worker, and then do any updates to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, GreyBeardedGeek - I read this a 100 times. However it seems you read only 50% of my question ;) because other events work without any issues. Why does `click`, `mousemove`, `mousedown` work at the same time where `dragstart` does not. In particular, because dragging is somewhat  related to mouse events. Moreover the `Renderer2` API looks like being designed for such kind of access.